# Fancybox iframe not working properly in IE in general

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox, doctype

Hope you can help me, I've tried almost everything.

I use Fancybox on my website to display iframes with embedded videos in a popup.

This is my initializer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.video-thumb").fancybox({
    width: 960,
    height: 600
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a target="_blank" class="video-thumb iframe" href="[link-to-youtube.video]"><span class="video-thumb-text">Get started</span></a>
```

It works perfectly in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but in IE the popup only appears, when I hard-refresh the page. 
If I activate the video on the first page by clicking the link, it appears as expected, but if I go to another page with another video and click the link, the popup doesn't appear and I get an error in console saying:

> SCRIPT438: The object doesn't support the method 'undefined'

The error is pointing at the beginning HTML-tag, but I can't see what is causing the error. I guess it must inside the fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js.

I have tried to change doc types to go away from quirks mode, I have added following into the head-tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

Can anybody please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what version of fancybox?